# What is the WSS extension?

Tags: http

I browsed to a page hosted by IBM and the page has a WSS extension... is this an IBM WebSphere page?

http://www-03.ibm.com/press/us/en/presskit/23540.wss

WebSphere is very similar to TomCat which hosts JSP (Java Scripting Pages).  I'm thinking it's IBM's alternative to JSP...still no clue though.

Comment: I thought "I'll just google this and answer quickly and get some free rep", but I can't find the answer (only about 5 mins of effort)... so I think this is a legit question, though I'd suggest the OP edit it to sound related to programming :)

Comment: I'll second that.. and +1 the answer, 'cause now I NEED to know.

Comment: It can easily be whatever. You can configure your webserver for wss extension while there are HTML pages behind it. Unless you really find an application with such an extension, it will be hard.

Comment: Based upon viewing the source, I can only guess it stands for something like "whitespace-stuffed".  They have td's in there that are spread over six lines!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This stands for: WebSphere Application Server Standard

It's exactly what I though it was.  Very similar to JSP/Tomcat.